# I'm confused about a topic about fixed variables

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, constants

I have defined a list pointer to type const, but then I changed the value of one of the arguments in the list, but the compiler did not get an error from me and changed the value to a new value. At first I suspected that maybe after changing the value of the pointer address changes and the pointer is pointing to a new list, but I got the pointer address after and before changing the argument and it was one.
Now I want to know how a list of type can change its value?

```
int main()
{
    
    const int k = 5;
    const char *list[k] =
                {
                "computer",
                "physics",
                "mathematics",
                "text",
                "book"
                };
    
    const char** p = list;
    cout << "before: " << (list + 4);
    list[3] = "arabi";
    //cout << "\n" << setfill('-') << setw(10) ;
    cout << "\nafter: " << list + 4;
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }
    char* ch = (char *)"plus";
    
}
```

[run][2]

Comment: `list` is not const. It is a modifiable array of const pointers to strings. You modified the list so that item #3 points to a different string.

Comment: Pointers in C++ are supposed to be read according to spiral rule which in the case means from right to left. So `list` is an array of mutable pointers to const-qualified char. Array of const-qualified pointers looks like this: `char const * const list[5]` Is is a good idea to keep `const` to the right.

Comment: you define an array of `const char *`s. the array itself is not const. you should either change the const data (for example `list[3][1] = 'a';`) or define the array itself as const (`const char * const list[k]`) to get an compile error

Answer (score 1):

`const char *arr[n]`
is an array, which stores elements of type `const char *`.

`const char *` is a pointer to (multiple) `const char`s, which cannot be modified.

Note, that the things that cannot be modified are the `char`s that are pointed to by the `const char *`. The `const char *` pointers themselves **can** be modified!

When you do `arr[3] = "arabi"`, you are not changing the value of the string pointed to by `arr[3]`(which you couldn't, as it is const), but you are changing the pointer itself(which is not const)!

Comment: std::printf("You're welcome!\n");

Answer (score 1):

`const` can be used in 2 ways when declaring a pointer:

```
// The value is modifiable, 
// The location where the pointer is pointing cannot be changed
const type* name;
```

..and:

```
// The value is not modifiable, 
// The location where the pointer is pointing can be changed
type* const name;
```

They can also be used in combination:

```
// The value is not modifiable, 
// The location where the pointer is pointing cannot be changed
const type* const name;
```

In your case, you are using the first one, so the values can be changed.

If you want the values to not be changed, you'll have to use:

```
const char* const list[k] =
{
    "computer",
    "physics",
    "mathematics",
    "text",
    "book"
};
```

Comment: `std::cout << "That's a cool way of saying thank you." << "You're welcome :)";`